# object automatically scaling while moving them on camera view

Tags: camera, scale

I have been going through the blender guru tutorial series of making a donuts in that I came across 
the keyframing while i was doing that i **was moving the object in camera view and the object is automatically scaling** but when i **quit the camera mode this dosent happen** and i was using locrot 
[image: image before moving in camera view]

[image: image after moving the object in camera view]

[image: image before moving]

[image: image after moving]

Comment: Hello :). That's just the camera perspective. When using wide lens, closer objects appear disproportionately larger :).